# Are there circles in $\mathbb{R}^d$ taking no rational values?

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

I recently stepped over a little detail in a thesis I still wonder about. If one looks at $\mathbb{Q}$, then it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and we have no problem finding real numbers that don't belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. That's fine so far.

No go to the $d$-dimensional case. Sure, we can find points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that don't belong to $\mathbb{Q}^d$, but is it possible to find a whole disk (rectangle, triangle, (Borel-)measurable set, whatsoever) $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ s.t. $\partial A\in\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\mathbb{Q}^d$? Or better, even a dense set $T\subseteq[0,\infty)$ and disks (or similar) $A_t$ with radius $t$ and $t\in T$ having this property?

In fact it doesn't even have to be $\mathbb{Q}^d$, one could just take any countable, dense set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ as well.

(Sry for wrong tags, I just had no clue to which branches this question belongs to)

Comment: Radius $r$ where $r^2$ is irrational.

Comment: Maybe I am under-thinking this but couldn't you simply use an interval with irrational endpoints?

Comment: Oh my, you are so right...my mistake was, that I haven't seen that in fact both coordinates have to be rational to belong to $\mathbb{Q}^2$. So points like $(1,\pi)$ make no problem...I should certainly make a break now...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. Fix any $x_0\in\mathbb R^d$ and any $r>0$. For any $\epsilon>0$, consider the family of concentric spheres $S(t)=\{y\in\mathbb R^d\mid |x_0-y|=r+t\}$ for $t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. This is an uncountable family of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb R^d$, so only countably many of them can meet $\mathbb Q^d$. All your variants follow by the same argument.

Comment: Perfect and fast answer, killing all cases. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The circle of radius $\pi$ (or $\sqrt[3]2$ or $1+\sqrt 2$) around the origin in $\mathbb R^2$ has no rational points .

Answer (score 2):

Consider a circle with an algebraic center $\mathbf{c}$ and a transcendental radius $r$.  For all points on the circle $\mathbf{x}$, $\|\mathbf{c} - \mathbf{x}\| = r$.  If any $\mathbf{x}$ were algebraic, then $r$ would have to be be algebraic too,